# Alert box is not appear when I submit data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

There are many similiar questions but I don't have any error, where I need to do changes.

I have put alert boxes in my code but non are appearing.

Here is my code-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $test= "select * from stable where Email = '$Email'";

    $queryResult = $conn->query($test);
    $foundRows = $queryResult->num_rows;
    if($foundRows >= 1)
        $mailerr="Email already register";
    else {
        header("location:student.php?id=".$row['id']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO stable
                    (Firstname,Lastname,DOB,Email,Phno,
                    Gender,Address,City,ZipCode,State,Country,
                    Hobbies,Course,id,Time,Date,IP) 
        VALUES('$Firstname','$Lastname','$Dob','$Email',
                '$Phno','$Gender','$Address','$City','$Zipcode',
                '$State','$Country','$Hobby','$Course','',
                '$Time','$date','$IP')";

        if($conn->query($sql))
?>
<script> alert('Data Inserted successfully');
    window.location.href='student.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>' </script>
<?php

    }
}
```

Comment: This line: `header("location:student.php?id=".$row['id']);` performs a server-side redirect, so the script with the alert in it never actually gets output. Since you're doing a JS redirect afterwards, you can probably do without the server-side redirect. (Although there are much better ways of validation than a JS alert.)

Comment: oaky. thakyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the script tag with all the js in string and echo it. it will work

```
        if($conn->query($sql)){
  echo "<script> alert('Data Inserted successfully')window.location.href='student.php?id="+$id+"</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $test= "select * from stable where Email = '$Email'";

    $queryResult = $conn->query($test);
    $foundRows = $queryResult->num_rows;
    if($foundRows >= 1)
        $mailerr="Email already register";
    else {
        header("location:student.php?id=".$row['id']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO stable
                    (Firstname,Lastname,DOB,Email,Phno,
                    Gender,Address,City,ZipCode,State,Country,
                    Hobbies,Course,id,Time,Date,IP) 
        VALUES('$Firstname','$Lastname','$Dob','$Email',
                '$Phno','$Gender','$Address','$City','$Zipcode',
                '$State','$Country','$Hobby','$Course','',
                '$Time','$date','$IP')";

        if($conn->query($sql)){
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Data Inserted successfully');
           window.location.href='student.php?id=".$id."';
           </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This line: header("location:student.php?id=".$row['id']); performs a server-side redirect, i was also redirect in script. so was happened